# React router 4 - how to handle big apps without nesting routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Context: React app with React Router 4.0

Now that the best practice changed and you should not nest routes, but rather include them in Components as seen in the [example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic), I'm wondering how this will turn out in the long run once the app grows. Will it not be superhard to follow the routes / components if you don't have one central place to look for them?

Have you used rr-4 for bigger apps? What's the best practice?

Pretty scary as I already had to do a lot of refactoring moving from rr-2 to rr-4, I wouldn't want to redo everything when it's much more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

meet the problem too, here is the solution that migrate from react-router 3.0:

app.js

```
    import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import routes from './routes';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import "./css/style.less";
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {ConnectedRouter, routerMiddleware} from 'react-router-redux';
import {Route} from 'react-router';
import store from './store';
import App from 'components/App';
import {load} from 'lib/utils';
import Dispatcher from 'views/Dispatcher';
injectTapEventPlugin();
export const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();
export const middleware = routerMiddleware(browserHistory);

class MainApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={ store }>
                <ConnectedRouter history={ browserHistory }>
                    <Route path="/" render={ (props) => {
                        routes.onEnter(props);
                        const { match } = props;
                        return (
                            <App>
                                <Route path={match.url} exact component={ load("Home") }/>
                                {
                                    routes.childRoutes.map((route,idx) => {
                                        return <Route
                                            path={`${match.url}/${route.path}`} component={ route.component }
                                            key={idx}
                                            exact={ !!route.exact }
                                        />
                                    })
                                }
                        </App>
                        );
                    } }/>
                </ConnectedRouter>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MainApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

router.js

```
import React from 'react';
import App from 'components/App';
const load = (moduleName) => {
    const module = require(`views/${moduleName}/index.js`);
    return module.default;
};


export default {
    path: '/',
    component: App,
    indexRoute: { component: load('Home'), },
    childRoutes: [
        { path: 'home', component: load('Home'), }
   ]
}
```